# Move result of a query from one server to another table on another server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, export, import

What are my options in moving result of a query in one server to another table on another server? Data contains ~400.000 rows so it won't be a quick one. (Both of them are SQL Server 2008 R2)

Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use the [SqlBulkCopy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx) class via SQLCLR. You can either code this yourself or simply download the Free version of [SQL#](http://www.SQLsharp.com/) (which I am the author of) which contains a stored procedure named `DB_BulkCopy` which encapsulates this functionality. In either case the assembly will need to be given a `PERMISSION_SET` of `EXTERNAL_ACCESS`.

If using the SQL# stored procedure, you would do something similar to the following:

```sql
DECLARE @MyQuery NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @MyQuery = N'select some stuffs; -OR- EXEC SomeProc;';

EXEC SQL#.DB_BulkCopy
    --@SourceType = N'MSSQL',
    --@SourceConnection = N'Context Connection = true;',
    @SourceQuery = @MyQuery,
    @DestinationConnection =
           N'Data Source=(local); Integrated Security=true; Initial Catalog=tempdb;', -- CHANGE!!
    @DestinationTableName = N'SchemaName.TableName',
    @BatchSize = 3000,
    @NotifyAfterRows = 1000,
    @TimeOut = 1000 -- seconds
    --@ColumnMappings = N'',
    --@BulkCopyOptionsList = N'TableLock|UseInternalTransaction' -- Optional; see descripton below
    --@RowsCopied = @Rows OUTPUT
```

**@BulkCopyOptionsList** values:

- `TableLock` = Obtain a bulk update lock for the duration of the bulk copy operation. When not specified, row locks are used.
- `UseInternalTransaction` = When specified, each batch of the bulk-copy operation will occur within a transaction.
- additional options described in the SQL# manual.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest method  which  we use is something like below

1. Create a table on destination server using the scripts generated from the table on the source server by right click and going through option of Tasks/Generate scripts.
2. Then run the below T-SQL to upload the data from source table to destination.

   INSERT INTO dbo.YourTableNameHere
   SELECT *
   FROM [SourceServer].[SourceDatabase].dbo.YourTableNameHere

For large data movement, refer to below discussion and answer for same:

[Copy a large data from sql query result](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/58533/copy-a-large-data-from-sql-query-result)

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have an option to use Excel as there are more rows to move than can be handled (64k)

Answer (score 1):

I restored the database's backup on the target server and issued an insert into select.

Answer (score 0):

The [tool](https://github.com/data-buddy/DataBuddy/blob/master/README.md) I wrote is a perfect fit.
I uses `sqlcmd` to export and import data.
You just provide *.sql file with query and connect parameters to it.